# Passing data from one form to another form's textboxes

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to pass the selected nodes from a treeview to another form that is displayed in the text boxes.

[image]

this is my code in TreeView1_NodeMouseDoubleClick event

the code works fine when the data from the selected treeview is shown in the same form, but the problem is when I want to pass it to the other form 4 nothing is shown and the debug shows me that if it receives the values ​​but they are not reflected, maybe my code to refer to the other form is wrong I would like a support with this case.

```
   Private Sub TreeView1_NodeMouseDoubleClick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.TreeNodeMouseClickEventArgs) Handles TreeView1.NodeMouseDoubleClick
        Dim nodeKey As String = TryCast(e.Node.Tag, String)
        Dim form4 As New Form4
        ' Dim nodetext As String = TryCast(e.Node.Tag, String)
        'Dim nodeKey As String = DirectCast(e.Node.Tag, String)
        If nodeKey IsNot Nothing AndAlso nodeKey.StartsWith("DIST") Then
            'You have double clicked a district node
            Dim IDDISTRITO As Integer = Integer.Parse(nodeKey.Substring(4))

            form4.lblco.Text = IDDISTRITO
            'Do something with the district id here
            '...
            form4.txtdis.Text = e.Node.Text
            form4.txtpro.Text = e.Node.Parent.Text
            form4.txtdepa.Text = e.Node.Parent.Parent.Text
        End If
    End Sub
```

so I call form 3 where is the treeview

```html
 Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim for3 As New Form3
        for3.Show()
    End Sub
```

Comment: How are you showing/opening Form4 ?

Comment: From form 4 I call 3 and from what I select from 3 I want it to go to 4

Comment: You know it's possible to have many instances of the same form, right? Therefore, you have have a _reference to a specific instance_ of the form you need. You pass that reference around like any other variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you assumed, yes you are referencing the forms incorrectly. Please follow this technique. In form3 class, declare a public variable `Public Dim form4 As New Form4`.
Then modify the form3 calling procedure like this:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim for3 As New Form3
    for3.form4 = Me
    for3.Show()
End Sub
```

Now modify your existing code to this :

```
Private Sub TreeView1_NodeMouseDoubleClick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.TreeNodeMouseClickEventArgs) Handles TreeView1.NodeMouseDoubleClick
    Dim nodeKey As String = TryCast(e.Node.Tag, String)
    ' Dim nodetext As String = TryCast(e.Node.Tag, String)
    'Dim nodeKey As String = DirectCast(e.Node.Tag, String)
    If nodeKey IsNot Nothing AndAlso nodeKey.StartsWith("DIST") Then
        'You have double clicked a district node
        Dim IDDISTRITO As Integer = Integer.Parse(nodeKey.Substring(4))

        form4.lblco.Text = IDDISTRITO
        'Do something with the district id here
        '...
        form4.txtdis.Text = e.Node.Text
        form4.txtpro.Text = e.Node.Parent.Text
        form4.txtdepa.Text = e.Node.Parent.Parent.Text
    End If
End Sub
```

I have not tested the above code, but I believe you have got the idea.

Answer (score 0):

Well I managed to solve it, the simplest thing was complicated, I publish the solution.

**form 4 by calling 3**

```html
 Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim for3 As New Form3
        AddOwnedForm(for3)
        for3.ShowDialog()
    End Sub
```

```html
just add this code and voila

Dim form4 As Form4 = CType(Owner, Form4)
```